# How can I save this baby bird?

Tags: safety, birds, feral, junior-pets

One baby bird came on my terrace today, what do you suggest I can do to save this baby? I think it is a pigeon. I kept it at a place other pigeons can easily see, but no other birds came around.

[image]

Comment: Google photo search is helpful, this is pigeon. I kept it at a place other pigeons can easily see.

Comment: are you sure, the parents are not available? You should first have a close look, because most bird-parents will feed their chicks further, even they fell from the nest. You could provide some sort of defense against predator, but with access for the parents to reach the child.

Comment: Lot of pigeons are around the place I kept the bird, and I kept it at some safe place with food and water.

Comment: Did you saw another bird feeding "yours"? Because if not, you need to feed it, or it qill starve. As it looks like, it is much too young (and too less feathered) to find it's own food... But be aware, that you maybe scare the parents, if you are around too much and do not touch the bird. If you chabge it's smell, the parents will not feed it anymore

Comment: No other birds came around, I helped bird having water. And kept tomato, cucumber and some grains around.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your country call a vet or a licensed Wildlife Rehabilitator.
They will be able to tell you what to do and where to bring the animal.
Taking care of a wild bird is not simple and needs experience which Wildlife Centres for example have. They will raise the bird and release it back into the wild.

Depending on your location (if you add that I might be able to find more specific information) locate an expert on bird rescue.
The link for NYC as an example of what to look for https://www.dec.ny.gov/animals/83977.html

As the [page for NYC](https://ny.audubon.org/birds-0birdsways-help/what-do-injured-or-orphaned-bird) states you can do this:

> While you wait for further instruction [from a Wildlife Rehabilitator], you can create a makeshift nest for the baby bird in a small Tupperware container or a similar round dish, completely lined with layers of toilet paper that prevent the baby from touching the container itself.

Comment: Maybe some mail-pigeon owner would offer help too? If it is really a pigeon...

Answer (score 3):

He needs food mashed to semi-liquid mush and put in his mouth. A pet shop may have prepared food for infant parrots. A pigeon would need grains and corn, not vegetables. I once had a crow about that age; his favorite food was earthworms (cut into pieces and put into his mouth, at first).